# How do you reset an iterator?

Tags: javascript, iterator

I'm learning about iterators/generators, and am wondering if there is a way to make the iterator reset itself? Like when after you call the last `.next()` is there a way to make it restart?

```
function nextName() {
   const current = names.next().value
  const output = document.querySelector("output")
  if (current) { 
      output.innerText = current.name
    } 
    else { 
     // code to reset it! currently I'm just displaying text
     output.innerText = 'Nothing left'
     }
}

function nameIterator(names) {
  let nextIndex = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      return nextIndex < names.length ? 
        { value: names[nextIndex++], done: false } :
        { done: true }
     }
  }
}
```

Here's a codepen to be more clear:  https://codepen.io/sammiepls/pen/romyKL?editors=1010

So when you click the button, it calls my iterator which will display the names in my names array one by one each time you click. How can I make it reset on the last click so it goes back to the first name?

So the display would be like:

Bob

Peter

Sally

Bob // get Bob again

In the codepen I have also written the iterator using a generator, is there anyway for that to also be able to reset back to the first one after yielding through the array?

Comment: You want to cycle?

Comment: first time on my life a see "function*"... but if you want to cycle this shall work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzvpRw?editors=1010. Just modified the const for var and some handcode to reset the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The general answer is that you can't reset an iterable in JS.** This is, as far as I know, by-design, although I'm not privy to the decision-making process that was used to reach that conclusion.

In your specific case however, you don't want to necessarily reset the iterator, you want to cycle through the array. In that case, you can use the modulo operator as follows:

```
function nameIterator(names) {
  let nextIndex = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      nextIndex = (nextIndex + 1) % names.length;
      return { value: names[nextIndex], done: false };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. So in this case, its only possible because we're tweaking the iterator function, but we can't change the way nameGenerator would work as they aren't reset-able?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, when the iterator is done reset it like so:

```
// code to reset it!
output.innerText = 'Nothing left'
names = nameGenerator(arr);
```

*Unless someone proves me wrong, there is currently no method to reset an iterator that I'm aware of.*

Working snippet example:

```js
const arr = [ {name: "Bob"}, {name: "Peter"}, {name: "Sally"} ];

let names = nameGenerator(arr);


function nextName() {
   const current = names.next().value
  const output = document.getElementById("output")
   if (current) { 
      output.innerText = current.name
    } 
    else { 
    // code to reset it!
      output.innerText = 'Nothing left'
      names = nameGenerator(arr);
    }
}
  
function nameIterator(names) {
  let nextIndex = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      return nextIndex < names.length ? 
        { value: names[nextIndex++], done: false } :
        { done: true }
    }
  }
}

function* nameGenerator() {
  let index = 0;
  while(index < arr.length) {
    yield(arr[index++])
  }
}

 document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", nextName)
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Oh yes that's exactly what I want! Somehow I can't get this example to work in the codepen though :/ All you're adding is this `      names = nameGenerator(arr);` in the else block right?

Comment: @sammiepls you need to change const names to let names

Answer (score 1):

You could change the index and take the remainder value, if the index is greater than the array index.

```
function nameIterator(names) {
    let nextIndex = 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            nextIndex++;
            nextIndex %= name.length;
            return { value: names[nextIndex], done: false };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to the thread to look for the answer myself, and here's what I came up with:

```js
class CyclicIter {

  constructor(arr) {
      this.arr = arr
      this._at = -1
    }
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return {
        next: () => {
          if (this._at < this.arr.length) {
            return {
              value: this.arr[this._at++],
              done: false
            }
          } else {
            this.reset()
            return {
              done: true
            }
          }
        }
      };
    };
  reset() {
    this._at = -1
  }
};

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const myArrayIterable = new CyclicIter(myArray)
console.log(...myArrayIterable); // can be called multiple times
```

this example may be trivial since I am super new to JS. Any suggestions are appreciated.